# Find exact match from a list within a file and delete matched lines

Tags: python, regex

I want to delete lines in a file which match exactly with given from a list.
So these are lines from a file:

```
"mail.com": "bad_domain"
"winsecmail.com": "bad_domain"
"win-security-mail.com": "bad_domain"
"win-securitymail.com": "bad_domain"
"www.dhlexpressmail.com": "bad_domain"
```

And for example I want to exclude exactly a line with "mail.com".
I tried something like:

```
excluded = [

  "mail.com",
  "imgstatic.eu",
  "mta5.am0.yahoodns.net",
  "static.xx.fbcdn.net"

]


def exclude_domains(domainsFile):

  pattern = re.compile(r'\b(?:%s)\b' % '|'.join(excluded))

  for i, line in enumerate(open('misp_domain.yml')):
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, line):
      print(match.group())
```

But it gives me all strings which contain "mail.com".

Comment: What's your input, what's in misp_domain.yml?

Comment: I pasted sample input from this file in first code block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The dots in the strings of your `excluded` list should be replaced with `\.`, because in regular expressions dot means "any character", but you need to match real dots.
2. The `\b` matches a word boundary, which roughly means that there is a non-word-character before the first character and after the last character ([reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)). Since `-` and `"` are non-word-characters, `\b` will match them, that's why your regex matches for example `"win-security-mail.com": "bad_domain"`. If you want to match only lines which exactly match any item in your `excluded` list, replace `\b` with `"`:

```py
pattern = re.compile(r'"(?:%s)"' % '|'.join(excluded).replace(".", r"\."))
```

Comment: Now it does not catch anything at all.

Comment: Strange... I tested it on your input strings and it works for me.

Comment: Here is my test: https://www.mycompiler.io/view/6uQgJMy

Comment: EDIT:
Forgot to uncomment function call :D Works fine now! Thank you very much!